# How to get data for all records in master from transaction collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

I have two collection one is master and other one is daily report data, I want to fetch a report in a way where it will return data for all records, with zero entry if not in report data.

Master collection :

```
keyword_master: 
[{
    'keyword': 'kw1',
    'bid': 2
},
{
    'keyword': 'kw2',
    'bid': 1    
},
{
    'keyword': 'kw3',
    'bid': 1.3
}]
```

Report data :

```
keyword_report
[{
    'keyword': 'kw1',
    'clicks': 20,
    'impression': 2000,
    'report_date': ISODate("2019-11-06T07:39:53.000Z")
},
{
    'keyword': 'kw2',
    'clicks': 21,
    'impression': 1800,
    'report_date': ISODate("2019-11-06T07:39:53.000Z")
},
{
    'keyword': 'kw3',
    'clicks': 3,
    'impression': 600,
    'report_date': ISODate("2019-11-06T07:39:53.000Z")
},
{
    'keyword': 'kw1',
    'clicks': 2,
    'impression': 100,
    'report_date': ISODate("2019-11-07T07:39:53.000Z")
},
{
    'keyword': 'kw2',
    'clicks': 8,
    'impression': 900,
    'report_date': ISODate("2019-11-07T07:39:53.000Z")
},
{
    'keyword': 'kw1',
    'clicks': 20,
    'impression': 2000,
    'report_date': ISODate("2019-11-08T07:39:53.000Z")
}]
```

with aggregation framework using lookup with keyword master, I want to fetch records for date 8 Nov 2019 like-

```
output: 
[{
    'keyword': 'kw1',
    'clicks': 20,
    'impression': 2000,
    'report_date': ISODate("2019-11-08T07:39:53.000Z")
},
{
    'keyword': 'kw2',
    'clicks': 0,
    'impression': 0,
    'report_date': ISODate("2019-11-08T07:39:53.000Z")
},
{
    'keyword': 'kw3',
    'clicks': 0,
    'impression': 0,
    'report_date': ISODate("2019-11-08T07:39:53.000Z")
}]
```

ie. for a date it will return all master records with zero if not there in report collection.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please explain clearly

Answer (score 0):

Use this following aggregation:

```
db.getCollection("master").aggregate([
    {
        $addField: {
            report_date: new Date("08-11-2019")
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "reportData",
            let: {keyword: "$keyword", report_date: "$report_date"},
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                    $and: [
                                        {
                                            $expr: {$eq: [{$dayOfMonth: "$report_date"}, {$dayOfMonth: "$$report_date"}]}
                                        },
                                        {
                                            $expr: {$eq: [{$month: "$report_date"}, {$month: "$$report_date"}]}
                                        },
                                        {
                                            $expr: {$eq: [{$year: "$report_date"}, {$year: "$$report_date"}]}
                                        },
                                        {
                                            $eq: ["$keyword", "$$keyword"]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                {
                    $group: {
                        _id: null,
                        clicks: {$sum: "$clicks"},
                        impression: {$sum: "$impression"}
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "matched"
        }
    },
    {  
        $unwind: {
            path : "$matched",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays : true 
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            keyword: "$keyword",
            clicks: {$ifNull: [ "$matched.clicks", 0 ]},
            impression: {$ifNull: [ "$matched.impression", 0 ]},
            report_date: "$report_date"
        }
    }
]);
```